# How to write a function to replace street names

Tags: php

```
$names = "Benjamin, Elijah, Lucas, Mason";

$plan = "name ,name ,name, city";
```

I cannot figure out how to bind these two variables so that the `$plan` variable matches `$names`. I need to look at the `$plan` variable and if there is “city”, replace name with city, that is, “Mason” well, for example, “Moscow”.

That's what it should be

```
$names = "Benjamin, Elijah, Lucas, Moscow";

$plan = "name ,name ,name, city";
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you show us the sample result?

Comment: To do this, you will need a way to determine what is a name and what is a city, are you cross referencing another data set? Or do you just want to match them as they are in your code

Comment: How you are creating this strings values ?

Comment: Definitely unclear. What point does $plan serve? If the data columns (by commas) are known beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code to start with:

```
// convert names and plan to arrays:
$names = explode(',', "Benjamin, Elijah, Lucas, Mason");
$plan = explode(',', "name ,name ,name, city");

// iterate over `$plan` and check if current item is "city"
foreach ($plan as $key => $item) {
    // if it is - replace element with same key in `$names`
    if (trim($item) == 'city') {
        $names[$key] = 'Moscow';
    }
}
 // implode so as to get string
echo implode(', ', $names);
```

Comment: Looks like OP wants to create a 1-to-1 relationship between $names and $plan